# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'left

Tags: python, list, class, attributeerror

I wrote a code for Lowest Common Ancestor of a Binary Tree search.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__ (self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

class Solution:
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root: 'TreeNode', p: 'TreeNode', q: 'TreeNode') -> 'TreeNode':
        if not root:
            return None
        elif root == p or root == q:
            return root
    
        l = self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q)
        r = self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q)
    
        if l and r:
            return root
        else:
            return l or r
```

However, when I try to call out the method for LCA -

```
s = Solution()
s.lowestCommonAncestor([3,5,1,6,2,0,8,None,None,7,4],5,1)
```

it gives me this:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'left'
```

Comment: can you fix the indentation?

Comment: The identation is not a problem. But, thanks! I did make a styling flaw when I posted the question.

Comment: Going off your type hinting, you should be giving a ```TreeNode``` instance not a ```list``` to ```lowestCommonAncestor``` so it should be ```s.lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode([3,5,1,6,2,0,8,None,None,7,4]),TreeNode(5),TreeNode(1))``` but this returns ```None```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function out of the solution class, you pass a list to your function but input of your function must be a instance of tree node class. You must create your input as a list of tree node class